# TSQL - Insert from a Table1 DB1 to Table1 DB2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have two DBs with identical structures and tables, and they both contain some identical and some different data.
my task is to transport all the records from DB1 to DB2, but I do not have to delete all the data present in DB2 before, I must first check if in DB2 there are different records from DB1, not present in DB1. If there is a different record in DB2 it should not be deleted. The problem that starting from the insert extrapolated from the DB1, can have the same IDs to the DB2 and therefore the insert command will give the duplicate key error.

I'm carrying out a manual operation, very onerous in terms of time:
With excel, in a card insert the result of the select of a table of the DB1, and in another card the result of the same table but of the DB2.
Subsequently, with the vertical search, I verify the data that are more on DB2. If I find them, group them and change the id (seeing the max id of the DB1 table), then I check the weak or related tables connected to them and change the external id to the strong table to which I changed the id and also changing the id of weak and relational tables, as done previously. all this with "update table set id = 15000 where id = 101"
Finally, put the extra records in place, do a delete of the rest and execute the inserts taken from the DB1. (all right)

But done this for every strong table, which in turn has "n" weak and relational tables is a massacre. (if done on one or two tables ok, but since it is happening to me often I need something a little more automated)

Do you have any info to give me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are both DBs on the same server? If not, you'll need to start by creating a linked server.

Comment: please post queries to create the relevant table(s) and to insert sample data